# HTML.TextBoxFor disabled not passing value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following bit in my view :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PersonnelId, new { disabled = "disabled" })
```

In my controller I have this :

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    PersonnelFacade.SavePerson(person);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Now when I check the person.PersonnelId it is empty.
When I remove the {disabled = "disabled" } it works fine but then I can change the PersonnelId which is not what I want to do.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could use `HiddenFor` + `DisplayFor` instead, or just add `HiddenFor` to what you already have. Anyway, it doesn't make sense to rely on this sort of protection on browser level. Anyone can send a forged POST query with `PersonnelID` changed to what they want.

Comment: Neither of these offer the same functionality as a disabled textbox?

Comment: In my sample I'm using it with PersonnelId. But I want to use the same for CreationDate, so users can see when the person was created or ModificationDate to display when the last change was made. The DisplayFor doesn't pass the value. THe HiddenFor, I can use for the PersonnelId, since you are not really supposed to see it. But I can't use it for CreationDate or ModificationDate, since those should be displayed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try making it readonly instead.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PersonnelId, new { readonly= "readonly" })
```

Comment: The "readonly" works ok, except that the textbox is still enabled. When I add the "disabled", it looses the value again.

Answer (score 10):

Try 2 values

1. PersonnelIdForDisplay
2. PersonnelId

Then on your view

1. @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PersonnelIdForDisplay, new { disabled = "disabled" })
2. @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.PersonnelId)